Create local network that allows 2 part communicate in no internet area
I findout project outsource name: OpenHD. They set up a local network that allows the ground unit to connect to the air unit (UAV), enabling app like: Qground, mission planner to see everything that's happening with the UAV ( video from camere, telemetry in ap)
But companion computer like a Raspberry Pi is really necessary for this purpose, since the setup with a Pi Zero 2, Pi 4, and 2 WiFi modules can cost around $150.
there are any commercial products that provide a solution similar to OpenHD or WiFiBoard that could be a more cost-effective and maintained option, rather than building it from individual components. China have one is SiYi but seem still costly (about $300 with HM30 and $280 with SIYI A8 mini).  
Now, i get another project DroneBride that I can development directly into 2 PI computer.
But yahh, i still find another Product can set up a local network that allows the ground unit to connect to the air unit (UAV), enabling app like: Qground, mission planner to see everything that's happening with the UAV ( video from camere, telemetry in ap)

Pi Zero 2W is about USD $15 each, and includes WiFi.
I'm not sure where you are, who your local supplier is, or what shipping costs would be, but $150 sounds really high.
It looks like you need a Linux OS (or Windows or Mac) to run OpenHD/Qground,
and I can't think of anything any cheaper than a Pi Zero 2W.
